# API Goo.gl и Ошибка 403 Delphi

Tags: delphi, http-status-code-403

Есть код:

```
begin
IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
RequestBody := TStringStream.Create('{"longUrl": "ru.stackoverflow.com"}',TEncoding.UTF8);
IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
IdHTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';  
IdHTTP.Request.Referer := 'www.googleapis.com';
idHttp.Post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id&key=AIzaSyD-a9IF8KKYgoC3cpgS-Al7hLQDbugrDcw',RequestBody);
memo1.Text:=  idHttp.Response.ResponseText;
end;
```

Выдаёт ошибку 430 Forbidden ну доступ запрещён,в настройках URL Shortener API я включил этот API, там появились графики статистики ошибок и тд, но полностью пустой.

Все примеры что нашёл в гугле не смог запустить и вообще сначала ошибки были 400 Bad Request, вот с этим кодом выдаёт ошибку 403, это значит запрос отправляется и он правильный, но почему доступ запрещён?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашёл сам ошибку по анализу рабочего php скрипта, ошибка была в самом url который я взял из описания в гугле, там было сказано создать POST запрос

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?fields=id&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "longUrl": "http://ru.stackoverflow.com"
}
```

А оказывается POST запрос нужно было отправить на https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

```
begin
IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
RequestBody := TStringStream.Create('{"longUrl": "ru.stackoverflow.com"}',TEncoding.UTF8);
IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
IdHTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';  
//  IdHTTP.Request.Referer := 'www.googleapis.com'; У меня и без реферера работает
memo1.Text:=idHttp.Post('https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyCgh2sZHFOrNy4ak4-4MOMsNH38kN3psv0',RequestBody);  
end;
```

В мемо получил такой ответ:

```
{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "https://го.гл/ad65gx",
 "longUrl": "http://ru.stackoverflow.com/"
}
```

Comment: Да нет, вы просто сгенерировали другой `KeyID`, который не требует `referer`. А наличие/отсутствие части `fields=id` в url, на результат не влияют. Так что, "нашёл сам ошибку" - это заблуждение.

Comment: Вернее, json ответ сервера будет содержать только поле `id`, если в запросе было указано `fields=id`. Но ошибка 403 была не из-за этого параметра.

Comment: Хах, тогда почему если я  добавлю в URL`url?fields=id&key=`, то у меня ошибка 403! А когда я отправляю запрос на URL `url?key=` без ID то всё ок???

Хахаха, сейчас убрал строку передачи реферера `// IdHTTP.Request.Referer := 'www.googleapis.com';` и ВСЁ тоже работает идеально! Получается реферер не обязателен

Comment: У меня, с вашим новым ключом и fields=id нету ошибки. А вот со старым ключом - есть. И да, я уже написал в комментариях, что ваш новый ключ не требует referer. Вы сами можете управлять требованием наличия/отсутствия referer через консоль управления или при генерировании ключа (я этим API не пользовался и конкретнее сказать не могу).

Comment: Главное что я нашёл рабочий вариант под свою делфи 10 seattle а так почему у вас с ID работает а без, нет, а у меня наоборот, это уже не важно)

Comment: У меня работает и с этим параметром и без него.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо кода ошибки, сервер обычно отдаёт ещё и пояснение о её причинах в теле ответа. И в вашем случае, сервер гугла отвечает:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
            "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.",
            "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=292824132082"
        }],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."
    }
}
```

И на сколько можно понять из сообщения, сервер требует чтобы в заголовках HTTP запроса было указано поле `Referer`:

```
IdHTTP.Request.Referer := '_ваш_referer_';
```

---

Небольшой хинт: для того, чтобы Indy не выбрасывал исключения на плохих ответах и сохранял текст ответа, есть специальные опции `hoNoProtocolErrorException` и `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` соответственно. Т.е. если вы сделаете вот так:

```
IdHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
VRespBody := IdHTTP.Post(Url, RequestBody);
```

то в `VRespBody` сохранится ответ сервера, даже при коде 403.

Comment: У меня делфи ругается на `hoWantProtocolErrorContent`, а на `hoNoProtocolErrorException`, попробовал я просто добавить реферер после строки: 


`IdHTTP.Request.Charset := 'utf-8';`
`IdHTTP[http].Request.Referer := 'www.googleapis.com';`


Ошибка 403, нашёл php скрипт, рабочий, пробую переписать под delphi

Comment: @lib Ругаться может из-за того, что у вас старая версия Delphi и Indy.

Comment: Indy 10.6.2.5 старая версия?

Comment: @lib Очевидно, что раз такой опции у вас нету, то версия старая. В Delphi Berlin 10.1 она присутствует. Самую свежую версию Indy вы всегда можете взять из svn http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Download/svn.EN.aspx